# How to improve Oracle Standard Edition's performance for testing?

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-19c, continuous-integration

There's a great post on StackOverflow about improving Postgres performance for testing.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407442/optimise-postgresql-for-fast-testing/9407940#9407940

However, there aren't any resources on doing the same for OracleDB. I don't have a license for Enterprise Edition, that has features like 'In-Memory' columnar storage that would almost definitely improve performance.

> https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/inmem/intro-to-in-memory-column-store.html

I'm really limited in what I can try in Standard Edition. It's running in a Docker container in a CI pipeline.  I've tried putting the tablespace on a RAM disk, but that doesn't improve performance at all.  I've tried fiddling with FILESYSTEMIO_OPTION, but no performance change.

Would anyone know of some more obvious things I can do in OracleDB in a CI environment?

Comment: Could you please provide a little more info by what you mean by "*for testing*"? Usually testing revolves around using actually queries that either directly mimic what you'll realistically run in production or a subset of that. Performance tuning with databases generally comes down more so to query tuning and schema architecture rather than tuning the specific options of the server and/or database itself (until you hit an edge case that would warrant that). Without an example schema and/or queries you'll be running in your database, it's hard to know what issues you'll encounter and...

Comment: ...what to recommend on how to resolve them. Also please note that StackOverflow post you linked is from almost a decade ago. A lot has changed over that timeframe where it may have been more normal to tune the server / database settings compared to today where things have greatly improved and have become more standardized.

Comment: So, I've joined a company that has OracleSE2 running in a CI pipeline. There's nothing that complex being done. No PLSQL.  It's just basic select and insert queries. Each test TRUNCATES all the tables at the start and does some simple Django web app stuff.

Comment: The bottleneck I think is IO consistency. It's just lots of small queries made by the Django ORM. Each time you create an Object it does the full connection and flush.

Comment: Cool so you're probably running into pretty standard performance issues. If you could please provide some of the example queries that you're running into the biggest bottlenecks on, the schema of the tables involved, and a rough idea of how big those tables are, that would be really helpful in debugging your issues. One step further would be Oracle's equivalent of the **execution plans** for those queries (sorry I don't know the exact term they use).

Comment: So, I can't really provide the exact schemas.  But we're talking about very standard webapp tables, really only varchars, dates, and primary keys, and max, 20 columns.  The tables themselves will have no more than 30 rows in them.

Comment: Yea sorry unfortunately you probably won't get much response without the main things I mentioned above just because they're important in understanding your issue. The devil's in the details, even a single column table with 1 row can perform poorly on a $100,000 server if architected and queried improperly or due to a bad **execution plan**. If you're concerned with sharing the exact details, just anonymize your schema and queries before posting them (there's tools out there to help do so). I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "*the full connection*" but it's doubtful you have an IO problem...

Comment: ...if your tables are as *tiny* as you mentioned (30 or so rows). I've worked with tables with 10s of billions of rows on standard SSDs and IO was hardly a concern.

Comment: As J.D said, you need to share more than that. But if you want fast loading of a table then make sure you are using insert statement with bulk array binds, you can easily manage 10s of thousands of rows inserted per second on commodity hardware. Likewise, with sensible queries on sensible tables with sensible indexing, you will see millisecond response times. Oracle will do a good job of using the memory you give it, you don’t need In memory for your data to be cached.

Comment: Not to mention things like: hardware capacity, OS, product versions ... and performance expectations: expected throughput or response times or concurrent users, and what you achieve now. Trying things and fiddling random parameters is unlikely to get you anywhere if you do not understand the data and workload

Comment: And it is important to point out that the “in-memory” option for Oracle actually presents selected tables in a columnar organisation - as opposed to the traditional row-based organization. It is specifically designed for analytics workloads on data warehouses. It is definitely not a magic solution for all workloads. It may or may not apply to your workload. I am curious as to what makes you think that it “ would almost definitely improve performance”

Comment: I think IO is the concern.  The queries aren't slow, there's just thousands of them.  People in the Django world really don't unittest that well and they'll use ORM objects as business logic objects that can't be patched out in tests.  So they'll often create thousands of objects that create thousands of roundtrips.  None of my queries take longer than 3ms, it's just 3ms x 100'000 is still 100s.